# SUM() over a many-to-many relation in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `stanje` and `transakcija` in a many-to-many relation, as shown in the image:

[image: tables]

I need a MYSQL clause that returns all rows in `stanje` joined by a `SUM()` of every `transakcija.iznos` connected to a given `stanje` .

So far I have tried

```
select SUM(t.iznos) 
    from transakcija t 
where transakcija_id in 
    (select transakcija_id from stanje_transakcija where stanje_id = ?)
```

which returns the `SUM()` correctly when given a `stanje_id`, but have no idea how to proceed, since I need sums for all rows in `stanje`.

Edit: added example output

```
------------------------------------
| stanje_id | naziv | SUM(t.iznos) |
------------------------------------
|     1     |   a   |     125.2    | 
|     2     |   b   |     -42.2    |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result/

Comment: How do I provide sample data?

Comment: you can put some data for your expect result or you can try my answer  @ace196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to use `JOIN` in thoes tables by `transakcija_id` column and `stanje_id` column.

From your expect result you can try to use `SUM` with `GROUP BY`

```
select t2.stanje_id,t2.naziv,SUM(t.iznos) 
from transakcija t 
INNER JOIN stanje_transakcija t1 on t.transakcija_id = t1.transakcija_id
INNER JOIN stanje t2 on t2.stanje_id = t1.stanje_id
GROUP BY t2.stanje_id,t2.naziv
```